# Php and Jquery PPT File Upload Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, upload

I use codeigniter upload library and jquery malsup form plugin for upload files. It works for all file types except .ppt file type.

When I try to upload .ppt file something is become strange. On upload .ppt file I printed std object and all 'i' chars become � char.

```
<pre>stdClass Object
(
    [object_�d] => 15768
    [object_type_�d] => 383
    [or�g�nal_object_�d] => 6745
    [object_t�tle] => Narin [ARGETİ1874]
    [object_descr�pt�on] => Moustafa
    [last_act�v�ty_�d] => 31859
```

Comment: add this before output: <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: @halojoy I already added